# Not receiving data from JSON source

Tags: json, cloudpebble, pebble-js

I'm attempting to make a Pebble app that reads data from a JSON URL.

However, no matter what I do I can't seem to make the data appear on the app.

When entering this code in:

```
console.log(data.contents.AvailableBal);
console.log(data.contents.CurrentBal);
```

I would expect to get a result back in the logs that would help but I only get:

```
[PHONE] pebble-app.js:?: None
[PHONE] pebble-app.js:?: None
```

And when viewing the app in the emulator, both values where the data should be, say "Undefined".

My code is as follows. Any help would be great!

```
var UI = require('ui');
var ajax = require('ajax');

var splashCard = new UI.Card({
  title: "Please Wait",
  body: "Downloading..."
});
splashCard.show();

ajax(
  {
  url: 'https://djkhaled.xyz/balance.json',
  type: 'json'
  },
function(data) {
  console.log(data.contents.AvailableBal);
  console.log(data.contents.CurrentBal);
var main = new UI.Card({
    title: 'Balances',
    body: 'Available Balance: ' + data.contents.AvailableBal +
'\nCurrent Balance: ' + data.contents.CurrentBal
});
  splashCard.hide();
  main.show();
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your JSON,

```
{
    "contents": [{
        "AvailableBal": "$0.00 CR",
        "CurrentBal": "$0.00 CR"
    }]
}
```

You can not directly access `data.contents.AvailableBal` because `AvailableBal` is not directly inside `contents`.  `contents` has an array
 and this array's first object (object at index 0) contains the object that has `AvailableBal` and `CurrentBal` keys.

I'm not a JavaScript developer but probably answer would be something like this,

```
var main = new UI.Card({
    title: 'Balances',
    body: 'Available Balance: ' + data.contents[0].AvailableBal +
'\nCurrent Balance: ' + data.contents[0].CurrentBal
});
```